# Nuxt.js | open a new page as modal window with a route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, nuxt.js

How can I achieve something like #dribble, #behance, old #twitter overlay? When you open a single project or post there you will see a modal with a route without leaving the page.

In simple words modal window with the route.

For example, when I visit `example.com/login` or `example.com/posts/1` the existing page content should remain and modal should come with a route.

I hope I made my point clear.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have a dialogue and load in it the component depending on the route?

Comment: Yes, something like this. I want to load a page or component but the existing page content should remain. eg: if I am on about page and I click on login link modal so the route should change to example.com/login with the login popup but the about page content should remain there. exactly like dribbble.com. Please if you check the dribble website.

Comment: I think this tutorial is what you need: https://dev.to/charleswritescode/how-to-display-a-route-as-a-modal-in-vue-js-iid

Comment: @Lana wasted 2 hours trying that tutorial out, doesnt work on nuxt only plain vue

Comment: Have you figured this one out yet mate? I'm also interested in seeing if it's possible in Nuxt.js

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change your url like this

```
methods: {
    onOpen() {
        history.pushState({}, 'Login', '/login')
    },

    onClose() {
        history.back()
    }
}
```

and in your modal component, use `onpopstate` event handler to close the modal when user hit back button.

```
mounted() {
  window.onpopstate = this.close
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.onpopstate = null
},
```